# How to localize COM classes?

Tags: visual-c++, com

I'm in trouble with localize my COM classes. I don't known how to localize `IErrorInfo` and other text in standard way. I have searched but found nothing. My COM classes is `IUnknown` interface, not dual interfaces.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you mean you want to change the message dynamically depending on ... what?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I want to change message dynamically depending on client locale. In the `IDispatch::Invoke` method, its have `LCID lcid` parameter to specified what locale to use. But, my client is early binding with my coclass, not late binding. So, `IDispatch::Invoke` is not an option.

Comment: You could use the GetThreadLocale function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318127.aspx

Comment: The standard way is LoadString().  It automatically locates the string resource to use from the thread's locale.  It is entirely unclear whether additional help is needed, it is unlikely.  Just make sure that your string resources are correctly localized.

Comment: Thanks for advanced. I have decided to use thread locale and `SetLanguage()` as @EuroMicelli suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "COM-standard" mechanism to provide a localization locale to a COM object.

COM is arguably too "low-level" for that. Automation conceptually sits a layer above COM and so `IDispatch`'s `Invoke` does provide an LCID argument; but even with `[dual]` interfaces, the standard implementation of `IDispatch` (`CreateStdDispatch` *et al*) doesn't pass the LCID down to the called method.

*(However, will the standard implementation provide the LCID if a method has an `[lcid]`-marked parameter? I don't know first hand, but it's implied so [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))*.

You will need to provide your own mechanism. I don't know what would be the most appropriate mechanism for your object. Some ideas:

- You could have all your methods take an explicit LCID parameter that the client has to fill-in. I would go ahead and mark the parameter with [[lcid]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and follow the rules in the MSDN documentation.
- You could have a `SetLanguage()` method that sets an object-wide language stored in the instance and which controls the language used by your messages.
- You could rely on the default system locale.